# Error handling click events in context menu

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to android so please be patient with me. I have inflated a context menu in my list view to show delete option which should delete its child listview when selected. However, I get an error when trying to handle this delete event. What am I doing wrong?

This is my Main Activity:

```
  // handling context menu clicks
        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.edit:
                    break;
                case R.id.delete:
                 noteactivity.actionDelete();
            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
```

This is my NoteActivity in which the delete method is called from.

```
NoteActivity noteactivity;
    public void actionDelete() {
            //ask user if he really wants to delete the note!
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogDelete = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("delete note")
                    .setMessage("really delete the note?")
                    .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if(mLoadedNote != null && Utilities.deleteFile(getApplicationContext(), mFileName)) {
                                Toast.makeText(NoteActivity.this, mLoadedNote.getTitle() + " is deleted"
                                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(NoteActivity.this, "can not delete the note '" + mLoadedNote.getTitle() + "'"
                                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("NO", null); //do nothing on clicking NO button :P

            dialogDelete.show();
        }

I get this error (Null pointer exception)

 me: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.app.ben.notetaker, PID: 27059
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.app.ben.notetaker.NoteActivity.actionDelete()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.app.ben.notetaker.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:87)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3224)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$PhoneWindowMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3663)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
                                                                           at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3121)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4048)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3807)
                                                                           at android.widget.DropDownListView.onTouchEvent(DropDownListView.java:116)
                                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10023)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your reference to

> noteactivity

is null.  You need to have something to call

```
actionDelete()
```

from.

Comment: sorry to bug you but could you be more specific? i need the alert dilog to appear in the main activity context

Comment: No problem. I don't know how to be more specific. You have to initialize a new NoteActivity or pass a reference to one. Currently, you're getting a null pointer on your noteactivity reference.